# NodeJS module.exports

Tags: node.js

I have 2 functions

```
    module.exports = (app, express) ->
  config = nconf.get("database:#{app.settings.env}")
  switch app.settings.env
    when 'production'
      app.db = mongoskin.db("#{config.host}:#{config.port}/#{config.name}",  {journal: false})
    else 
      app.db = mongoskin.db("#{config.host}:#{config.port}/#{config.name}",  {journal: false})

module.exports.db = (db , env) ->
  config = nconf.get("database:#{env}")
  switch env
    when 'production'
      db = mongoskin.db("#{config.host}:#{config.port}/#{config.name}",  {journal: false})
    else 
      db = mongoskin.db("#{config.host}:#{config.port}/#{config.name}?",  {journal: false})
  return db
```

At some places we are using the 2nd function. However, we would like to get rid of one function. How can we go about doing it without passing the app parameter ? 
Is there a better way to define the 1st function ?

Thanks,
Raja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a DBSingleton class and using that object everywhere.